# How to highlight multiple words in vim

Tags: vim

I am checking a log file using vim. There's only one word can be highlighted, when I search another word,the second word is highlighted but the previous one is not highlighted anymore.

Can anyone show me a way that easily highlight/cancel highlight multiple words in vim? For example, I want to highlight words "stack", "over" and "flow", then I want to cancel the highlight of "stack" and highlight another word "error". So that I can analyze the log more efficiently. 
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ad hoc text highlighting in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231172/ad-hoc-text-highlighting-in-vim)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to highlight multiple searches in (g)vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704434/is-there-any-way-to-highlight-multiple-searches-in-gvim)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`/\v\/folder|\/copy` - search for `\folder` and `\copy`

and add to `.vimrc` `set hlsearch`

Comment: Thanks, I can use `/stack\|over\|flow` or `\vstack|over|flow` to search these words, and they are all highlighted.

Answer (score 29):

There are two simple ways to highlight multiple words in vim editor.

1. Go to search mode i.e. type '**/**' and then type **\v** followed by the words you want to search separated by '**|**' (pipe).
   Ex: **/\vword1|word2|word3**
2. Go to search mode and type the words you want to search separated by '**\|**'.
   Ex: **/word1\|word2\|word3**

Basically the first way puts you in the regular expression mode so that you do not need to put any extra back slashes before every pipe or other delimiters used for searching.

Answer (score 3):

To have all words highlighted in the same color and be able to search and replace all of then, add them as alternatives to the search pattern, e.g. `/foo\|bar`. My [SearchAlternatives plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4146) provides handy mappings to add and remove patterns.

If you want different colors for different matches, you need a highlight mechanism different from the built-in search. My [Mark plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666) is used by many people for that. (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)